# NVIDIA GPU fan won't spin under 30% in Ubuntu - Noise is crazy

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, fan

In Ubuntu the fan noise when idle is driving me crazy. The GPU temperature might be 25c, and the fan keeps spinning furiously.

I have a 3060TI. The fan can't be set under 30% no matter what I do. I can confirm I have fan control from 30% and higher. When I manually raise the fan control in nvidia-settings I can hear the fan speed up. However, whenever I set the fan speed to under 30%, the slider reverts to 30%. Ubuntu also does not respect the fan curve I set in Greenwithenvy.

What I've done so far: I have coolbits set to 4, I have installed Greenwithenvy, and have the Nvidia 525 driver.

By contrast, in Windows the fan speed can be set to 20% when idle and is pleasantly tolerable. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have your card so I can't test but I did find an answer regarding overclocking that is setting fan speed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1368739/225694) I hope it helps you.